# What are the major issues to look for when moving an application built in Qt for a Symbian platform to a Windows Mobile platform?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-mobile, symbian

I have an existing application created using Qt for the Symbian operating system and I want to port it to Windows Mobile devices.

I'm expecting some presentation differences. What additional things should I look out for?

Answer (score 1):

Qt strives for exactly this kind of cross-platform development, so the library itself should handle everything.

I'm not an expert on mobile devices, but a simple recompile *should* work just fine, assuming your code uses the abstractions Qt provides (no native calls, `qptrdiff`, `Q_INT64_C()`, etc.).